# How do you add a device to the XAML designer preview in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

How do you add a device at the XAML designer (Android) in Visual Studio 2019? So not the emulator but only the at the design screen?

I found [this](https://blog.mzikmund.com/2017/02/how-to-add-new-preview-devices-to-the-visual-studio-xaml-designer/) on the internet but that doesn't work at Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this to get different devices layout for designing xaml,

[image: First Click on this]

[image: And Here is the option you looking for]

Comment: I undestand, but how do I add some different sizes to this devices? So 1200x600 or something?

Comment: this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided,  i follow the steps, it works well for UWP.

[image]

As i know, Xamarin.Forms doesn't currently support visual designers for XAML files.

You could check the link below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/questions/forms-xaml-designer